# Win2012r2 Services Recovery Tab documenation refuses to launch

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, batch-file, windows-service, troubleshooting

Services Recovery Tab **Help** will not launch.

[[image: Windows Services.msc "**Help me set up recovery actions**" results in "An internal error occurred (INVALID_HANDLE)"]Windows Services.msc "Help me set up recovery actions" results in "An internal error occurred (INVALID_HANDLE)"[1]]

On the "**Recovery**" tab in Windows Services.msc, clicking on
"**Help me set up recovery actions**"
results in
"**An internal error occurred (INVALID_HANDLE)**"

[Original title was "Win2012r2 Services Recovery Tab Help refuses to ... well HELP." was rejected because the word help was in the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title).

(Nor will the C:\APPS\PrintFailures.bat batch file show any evidence that is was launched.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the same error on any Server 2012 R2 I checked, but I also see it on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 TP5. So I think there is no problem with your installation, it's a bug in the OS that nobody cares to fix.

The help file that is suppose to be opened is:

```
%SystemRoot%\Help\Mui\0409\sys_srv.chm
```

but that file doesn't seem to exist on Server 2012 R2 or newer. Even copying it from a 2008 R2 server doesn't help.

In my experience the help links in newer Windows versions are often broken, just use Google or Bing.

Comment: Thanks for the file path as that should be useful.  Using the built-in help is safer and provides fewer distractions.

Comment: i hate it that Microsoft thinks it is a good idea to browse the web with Administrator privilege.

Answer (score -1):

You have some antivirus on the system without the proper exclusions.  Use defender or configure the exclusions properly.

Comment: Disabling AV or adding %SystemRoot%\Help\ to the exclusions and error still no luck.